# Find generating function for the numeric function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

The numeric function is:
$$0\cdot5^0, 1\cdot5^1, 2\cdot5^2, \ldots, r\cdot5^r,\ldots$$

My solution is:

$$\begin{align*}
&\frac5{1-5z}=1+5z+(5z)^2+\ldots\\\\
&\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac1{1-5z}\right)= 0 + 1\cdot5 + 2\cdot 5^2 \cdot z +\ldots& [\text{diffentiating wrt }z]
\end{align*}$$

Multiply above by $z$ and we get the generating function, which can be written as:

$$z\cdot\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac1{1-5z}\right) = \frac{5z}{(1-5z)^2}$$

But, the ans given in ans book is:

$$\frac{z}{5(1-(z/5))^2}\;.$$

Is my solution wrong?

Also, please provide solution for these numeric functions as well:

1. $1, -2, 3, -4, 5,\ldots$
2. $1, \frac23,\frac39,\frac4{27},\ldots,\frac{r+1}{3^r},\ldots$
3. $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,\ldots$
4. $0\cdot1, 1\cdot2, 2\cdot3, 3\cdot4,\ldots$

Comment: Please format your question with mathjax or latex. It is currently very difficult to read. Here are some pointers http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: How to add the formatting? For eg, I have used ^ for superscript but it shows ^ only. I am new this.

Comment: Wrap your math in "$\$$" symbols. For example, to make d(1/(1-5z))/dz look better type out $\$$ \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-5z}\right) $\$$ which when compiled will look like $$ \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-5z}\right) $$ You can also right click on math, click show math as $\to $ Tex commands to get a modal window containing the latex that generates that math.

Answer (score 0):

$$A(z)= 0.5 + 1.5z + 2.5z^2 + ...$$
You can take 5z out from the equation.
It'll turn out to be like
$$A(z)=5z[1 + 2.5z+3.5z^2+...]$$
Using the series expansion
$$(1-x)^y = 1 +2x +3x^2 + 4x^3 +...$$
where y= -2 (I couldn't display it properly in the above equation so yea, had to put a y there). We will end up with
$$A(z)=5z(1-5z)^y$$
where y= -2, again.
Therefore,
$$A(z)=5z/(1-5z)^2$$